# Cursor to insert .pdf files into a table

Tags: sql-server-2014, cursors

I need to insert all .pdf files from a folder, in a table, according to its number.

I could get a list of files ( I have all .pdfs inside a folder ):

```
exec master.sys.Xp_dirtree 'The_Folder_where_PDFS_are',0,1
```

And I could insert it inside a table:

```
CREATE TABLE PDFTest(NumExample integer,image_data VARBINARY(MAX));

DECLARE @NumExample integer
SET @NumExample = 2456789

INSERT INTO PDFTest(NumExample ,image_data)
SELECT @NumExample ,image_data
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\DBA\3937052016_Requisição.pdf',SINGLE_BLOB) AS ImageSource(image_data);

Select * from PDFTest
```

But as you can see, files are named after a number ( `3937052016` ). This number is the ID of another table, so, if the PDF file starts with `123`, I need to insert it into the ID `123`. I just would like a start point. I'm trying to create a cursor, looping throug all files, and using left() or substring () function to get the number, inserting it into a variable, and comparing it , like `insert this pdf into table where left/substring(pdf_name)=id`.

I need something like a string like this :

```
Insert into tablex ( pdffield ) 
values ( 123_PdfFIle.pdf ( obviously using openrowset )
 where left/substring(123_pdf to get the pdf's code )) = id`
```

I'm on the right patch? Is there a way to do this with less efforts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a directory called c:\TestPdf and created two txt files with some text in them (you would use your pdf files)

```
123456789.txt
987654321.txt
```

From your example, my assumption is you want file 123456789.txt inserted as ID 123 and you want file 987654321.txt inserted as ID 987.

This dynamic SQL worked for me - you would need to test against your data

```
set nocount on
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.PDFTest', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.PDFTest; 
Create table PDFTest (NumExample integer,image_data VARBINARY(MAX))
DECLARE @FileTable TABLE (FileName VARCHAR(max),DepthColumn INT,FileColumn INT)

INSERT INTO @FileTable
EXEC master.sys.Xp_dirtree 'c:\testpdf',0,1

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(max)

DECLARE _CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT FileName
FROM @FileTable

OPEN _CURSOR

FETCH NEXT
FROM _CURSOR
INTO @FileName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = '
INSERT INTO PDFTest(NumExample ,image_data)
SELECT ' + substring(@FileName, 1, 3) + ',image_data
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N''c:\testpdf\' + @FileName + ''',SINGLE_BLOB) AS ImageSource(image_data)
'

    PRINT @cmd

    EXEC (@cmd)

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM _CURSOR
    INTO @FileName
END --End While

CLOSE _CURSOR

DEALLOCATE _CURSOR

SELECT *
FROM pdftest
```

Comment: Well I make a lot of changes and a lot of tables and inserts and joins to fit what i need but this cursor helped me 90%. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it help a little anyway :)